# how to reverse the lower case characters in word using only sed

Tags: bash, scripts, c, bashrc, sed

Reverse every word of a line using sed

```
   Description
   -----------

   The job to do is reversing every word of a line.

   that a word is a sequence of lowercase alphabets

   Raw Input
   ---------

   112358 is a fibonacci sequence...
   a test line
   124816 1392781
   final line...

   Desired Output
   --------------

   112358 si a iccanobif ecneuqes...
   a tset enil
   124816 1392781
   lanif enil...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sed script will do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed

# Put a \n in front of the line and goto begin.
s/^/\n/
bbegin

# Marker for the loop.
:begin

# If after \n is a lower case sequence, copy its last char before \n and loop.
s/\n\([a-z]*\)\([a-z]\)/\2\n\1/
tbegin

# If after \n is not a lower case sequence, copy it before \n and loop.
s/\n\([^a-z]*[^a-z]\)/\1\n/
tbegin

# Here, no more chars after \n, simply remove it before printing the new line.
s/\n//
```

Comment: Nice solution. It works on the example. A word that starts with a capital letter will get all its lower characters reversed.

Comment: @McNisse: according to the definition of 'word' in the problem, the sequence "Hello" only contain the word "ello", and the sequence "HelloWorld" contains 2 words: "ello" and "orld" (this is my reading of the problem statement, as if we use spaces as word delimiters, "line..." is not a word and should not be reversed).

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-reverse-string-in-unix-shell-script/) is very good. Sample: `echo "nixcraft" | rev`. And for the SED part, heres from this [link](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/do_it_with_sed.txt).

[image]

Comment: see the raw input clearly. this solution reversing numbers also but I need output as only reversing the lower case characters..

Comment: go to 2nd link, you will find all about sed.